# Adjusting the font size in Xcode's Developer Documentation window?

Tags: xcode

The small font size in dark mode makes it difficult to read. Is there a way to increase the size?

Comment: You‘d think with all the effort Apple has put into accessibility that something as simple as offering a command-+/- to scale the documentation content would just be included by default. Until Apple fixes this deficiency, I’m viewing [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/) in a web browser (which has its own deficiencies: no dark mode support yet, not auto-loaded from the IDE, and doesn’t have the sidebar for navigating the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the **Developer Documentation Window** specifically.

You can take advantage of using a nice feature under **Zoom** accessibility options in system preferences. It has a feature that let you set the font of anything you mouseover while holding a key:

[image: Zoom]
(Screenshot from macOS 10.15)